# Cannot install any software using terminal because of multiple dependency issues

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I cannot install any software using terminal.

It is showing the following logs.

```
swarathesh60@swarathesh60-Lenovo-Y40-80:~$ sudo apt -f  install gdebi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gdebi : Depends: gdebi-core (= 0.9.5.7ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: gksu but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: gnome-icon-theme but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: libgtk2-perl but it is not going to be installed
 imagemagick : Depends: imagemagick-6.q16 (= 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.3)
 network-manager-gnome : Depends: libnma0 (= 1.2.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) but 1.2.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 is to be installed
 software-properties-gtk : Depends: python3-software-properties (= 0.96.20.2) but 0.96.20.5 is to be installed
 ubuntu-session : Depends: gnome-session-common (= 3.18.1.2-1ubuntu1.16.04.2) but 3.18.1.2-1ubuntu1.16.04.1 is to be installed
 update-notifier : Depends: update-notifier-common (= 3.168.1) but 3.168.3 is to be installed
 vim-tiny : Depends: vim-common (= 2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2) but 2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt -f install`?